# Return Average based on Per Item in each line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Data as follows from a select Statement from ItemDetails Table:

INPUT [Same Ref]:

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |

Expected OUTPUT [Same Ref - Do AVG]:

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 40.50 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 40.50 | A1 |

INPUT [Same Ref but Different ItemValue] :

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 30 | A1 |

Expected OUTPUT [No Change to Value]:

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 30 | A1 |

Expected INPUT [ Different Ref Same ItemValue] :

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 81 | A2 |

Expected OUTPUT [ No Changes to ItemValue]:

| ItemNo | ItemValue | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITM001 | 81 | A1 |
| ITM002 | 45 | B1 |
| ITM001 | 81 | A2 |

Rows are duplicating due to other column s.

```
SELECT ItemNo, AVG(ItemValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo) / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNo) AS ItemValue 
FROM ItemDetails ;
```

seems not working .

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Do you really want three rows of output, or would just two be better (one for `ITM001`, one for `ITM002`? Put another way, there are multiple ways to get at the expected results, given those inputs, but only one of the approaches will be correct given the reasons behind wanting that particular data.

Comment: You're trying to remove duplicates after averaging, a classic mistake not unlike engaging in land wars in asia. You can't do it, but you can fix your join so you first aggregate stuff and then join in the duplicates

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn. Thank you for your comment. yes, it seems Duplicate row but due to other  column ItemNo seems duplicated. I have added/edited original question Ref column to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the outputs you indicated in your post; note that if your ItemValue column is a float, this will behave unpredictably and should be cast to a decimal or numeric type first.

```
/*
CREATE TABLE #ItemDetails (
  ItemNo NVARCHAR(255),
  ItemValue DECIMAL(10,2)
)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM001', 81)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM002', 45)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM001', 81)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM003', 81)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM004', 45)
INSERT INTO #ItemDetails VALUES ('ITM003', 30)
*/
WITH DuplicateCounts AS (
  SELECT
    ItemNo,
    ItemValue,
    COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount
  FROM
    #ItemDetails
  GROUP BY
    ItemNo,
    ItemValue
)
SELECT 
  I.ItemNo,
  I.ItemValue/D.DuplicateCount AS ItemValue
FROM 
  #ItemDetails I
INNER JOIN
  DuplicateCounts D
ON
  I.ItemNo = D.ItemNo
  AND I.ItemValue = D.ItemValue
```